# How to Set Vuetify's <v-otp-input> to Accept Only Numeric Input

Tags: vuetify.js

anyone knows how can I set the <v-otp-input> component in Vuetify to only accept numeric input and prevent the input of characters and other types of data?

There's no clear custom instructions on Vuetify website. ( https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/otp-input/#usage )

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with the

> type="number"

Comment: yes but it didn't work

Comment: actually it works: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vite-4bxokd?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FForm.vue

Comment: Even no ```type=number``` you can actually type a number. But I think the OP's problem is, when you type number then re-type character in *v-otp-input*, it clear/removes the value.

Comment: hi @huanfeng thanks for your response. However I can still input other types of values in the <v-otp-input> field. I want it to accept only numerical values. Please check out this clip : https://youtu.be/3STYhTVbSKs

Comment: hi @Newbee, sorry I didn't make my question clear. I want to restrict the input to only accept numerical values, but I'm still able to enter other types of values.